# Find perfect number using while loop in R

Tags: r

I was trying to find perfect number.
Perfect number is that the sum of its factors(including 1) equals itself.
I need to find the first and second perfect number 6 and 28.
So I start from number 2 until I find 2 perfect numbers.
Here is the code:

```
num.perfect <- 2
count <- 0
iter <- 2
while(count < num.perfect)
  {
  divisor <- 1
  for(i in 2:iter)  #find the factors of a number
    {
    if(iter%%i==0)
    {
      divisor <- c(divisor, i)
    }
    }# end for loop
  if(sum(divisor)==iter)      #print the perfect number
    {
      print(paste(iter, " is a perfect number", sep=""))
    count <- count + 1
  } # end if
  iter <- iter +1
} # end while loop
```

But the loop keeps running and will not stop. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. What is the purpose of the loop can you describe more the purpose of the elements.

Comment: I assume you are looking for perfect number based on [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)? The sum of proper positive divisors excludes the number itself, so it should be `if(iter%%i==0 & iter != i)` instead of `if(iter%%i==0)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a function in R to find perfect numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724735/write-a-function-in-r-to-find-perfect-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code and see whether it does what you want:

```
facs=function(n) head((1:n)[n%%(1:n)==0],-1)
 perf=function(x){
 k=numeric(x)
   m=i=0
   while(m<x){
      i=i+1
      if(sum(facs(i))==i){m=m+1;k[m]=i}
  }
 k
}
perf(4)
# [1] 6 28 496 8128
```

Comment: Whats the difference of using `<-` or `=` in assignment?

Comment: Whats the difference of using `<-` or `=` in assignment? I prefer `=` to `<-` since I consider `<-` as a forced assignment. Although I might be wrong:             eg: `max(s<-c(3,4,5))>4` will not only tell me whether the maximum of `3,4,5` is greater than 4 but will also ensure `s` is a vector ie `s=c(3,4,5);max(s)>4` can be condensed to `max(s<-c(3,4,5)>4)`

Comment: Am sorry. On trying to run the edits that you made, some objects within were not found. So sorry but I have to revert the code to the way it was before you did edit it. Please before an edit try running the edit that you want to make.  Thnak you